# Wordpress file download has no extension only in Firefox

Tags: php, html, wordpress, firefox

This code for a download button in Wordpress works in Chrome, but in Firefox, the image gets downloaded without an extension.

```
<div class="download-button">
Download: <a target="_self" 
    href=" <?php 
        $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'full', false );
        echo $src[0]; // the url of featured image?> " 
        download="<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>" 
        width="<?php echo $src[1]; ?>" 
        height="<?php echo $src[2]; ?>" 
        title="<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>" >
        <?php echo $src[1]; ?>x<?php echo $src[2]; ?>
    </a>
 </div>
```

If you use "Save target as" it does have a extension.

Why does it save with the extension when it is downloaded?

Comment: What is the actual HTML output of the above code?

Comment: Does the title have an extension in it, if not then it is firefox the one working correctly